# Huge amount data + Objectbox + RecyclerView adapter

Tags: android, database, android-recyclerview, objectbox

Android newbie. 
I have stored 100,000 items in Objectbox database.

Before I show RecyclerView, I have to update the dataset everytime(Because of add, remove items). So I call `myRecyclerViewAdapter. setDataset(myObjectBox.getAll())`.

So before showing the UI, the query takes little bit time, the UI lags. After that, the UI works normally.

Is there any workarounds to speedup the query?

Comment: use lazy loading (`io.objectbox.query.LazyList<E>`)

Comment: Thank you @pskink, but i don't know how to use LazyList. Can you give me a little code example.

Comment: Already did that, but i can't get the point. Confused about partial loading, caching, etc. A code example with RecyclerView implementation is helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should not query huge amounts on the main thread. Check [reactive queries](http://objectbox.io/documentation/data-observers-reactive-extensions/).

Minimal example:

```
Query<Task> query = taskBox.query().build();
query.subscribe(subscriptions)
     .on(AndroidScheduler.mainThread())
     .observer(data -> updateUi(data));
```

Please read the [full docs](http://objectbox.io/documentation/data-observers-reactive-extensions/).

Comment: Happy to hear from you Mr.Markus. I will try in code, but will be happy, if you put an example implementation with RecyclerView on github or somewhere else. Helpful for newbies like me.

Comment: One question: I called `notifyItemRemoved()` whenever i remove an item. But didn't make any call when add an item. But the code still works correctly. How? Is it necessary to call `notifyDataSetChanged()`?

Comment: Everyone should definitely try Objectbox... it's mind blowing!

Comment: The observer is triggered automatically on updates. It's documented in the link I gave in the answer.